# Cell Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, type-mismatch

I need a for loop to skip an index value and I do not understand why this code doesn't skip the 6th index value in the loop.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Exceptions = 0
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If i <> 6 Then
        If (Cells(i, Selection.Column).Value - Cells(i + 1, Selection.Column).Value) > 0.1 And Cells(i, Selection.Column).Value > 90 Then
            MsgBox ("The ticker start value is: " & i - 6)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
    If Cells(i, Selection.Column) = "" Then
        Exceptions = Exceptions + 1
    End If
    If Exceptions > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("No start found")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The problem I'm running into is that the 6th row contains text and the boolean does math on the cells. So when the loop gets to the 6th row it crashes. However, this loop continues to crash despite supposedly not having to deal with anything in the 6th row.

Comment: can you share sample data? or image of the spreadsheet, and I don't think `If (boolean) Then` is set correctly

Comment: Is this the whole code snippet? It works fine for me. (of course without the `If (boolean) then`)

Comment: More info please. You simply say it crashes. Your title says 'Cell Type Mismatch'. Which error are you getting, and is it definitley when i = 6? What line?  What does `boolean` do? You shouldn't need parentheses because that just evaluates the boolean. `Rows.Count` could be causing some issues if there is an overflow also. Not enough information....

Comment: How is this code supposed to reproduce the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: My money is on an error value in some cell that `boolean` is checking, assuming a specific data type. Only a `Variant` can receive an error value, and you can't compare an error value against a string or anything.

Comment: You are aware that only the first if is exclude when the row is 6? The last two will fire no matter what row number.

Comment: Yes. The other if statements do not error out.

Comment: How did you declare `i`? As you have it, try `If i <> "6" Then ...`  ...also, are you *sure* you want this to run for every single row? That's going to likely cause Excel to appear frozen (or maybe actually freeze). I suggest setting a `lastRow` somehow.

Comment: Insert `Debug.Assert(Not IsError(Cells(i, Selection.Column).Value))` before the `If Cells(i, Selection.Column) = "" Then` line. Run your code, if the VBE breaks on the assert, your data contains error values and you can't compare that to an empty string.

Comment: `Cells(i + 1, Selection.Column).Value)` will return the value from row 6 when i = 5 and you are trying to subtract text from a number.  You may want to exclude row 5 also.

Comment: What's special about row 6 anyway?

Comment: @Mat'sMug from the OP: `The problem I'm running into is that the 6th row contains text`

Comment: @ScottCraner *mug crawls back to his hole* ;-)

Comment: @ScottCraner That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner, I know this is 5 years later... but if you want... you can convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.